# c# Return All Array Values Not Found

Tags: c#, arrays

I have code which loops through XML elements within multiple documents, and checks for a matching values within an array (cpltfids). If it finds a match for one of the array values in any of the XML elements, it creates a hard link for the file found in the XML.

The loop works fine for creating all of the hard links, but I am struggling to add code to do two more things:

1. If none of the array values are found in any of the XMLs, stop and do nothing.
2. Return the value of all array values that are never found at the end of the loop, so I can write them into a Message Box / Write Line at the end.

   ```
   foreach (var assetC in assetElements)
   {
       var innerElementsC = assetC.Descendants(assetns + "Id").FirstOrDefault().Value;

       if (!Array.Exists(cpltfids, element => element.Value == (innerElementsC)))
           continue;

       var assetname = assetC.Descendants(assetns + "Path").FirstOrDefault().Value;
       var assetpath = Directory.GetFiles(assetmapdir, (assetname))[0].ToString();

       CreateHardLink(Path.Combine(textBox3.Text, (assetname)), (assetpath), IntPtr.Zero);

   }
   ```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your comments. I am a total newb.

Summary of what I'm trying to do:

1. User loads x number of "CPL xml documents into a listbox.
2. Search x number of directories up (i will add more iterations later) from the xml(s) loaded and look for x number of files called ASSETMAP.xml
3. Parse all ASSETMAP.xml files and see if there are uuid matches with uuids in the user loaded xml.
4. For all matches found, construct the path to the files those uuids belong to, and make a hard link for each one in user specified dir.

The foreach loop lives inside a method i'm calling elsewhere in the program. Here is more context:

**Method:**

```
public bool UpdateNameInAssetmap(XDocument doc, string uuid, string newName)
    {
        var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        var assetElements = doc.Descendants(ns + "Asset");
        var result = false;

        foreach (var assetC in assetElements)
        {
            var innerElementsC = assetC.Descendants(ns + "Id").First(); //nav to uuid id element in assetmap 
            if (!innerElementsC.Value.Equals(uuid))
                continue;

            var chunks = assetC.Elements(ns + "ChunkList").First().Elements(); //nav to chunk list element

            foreach (var chunk in chunks)
            {
                chunk.Elements(ns + "Path").First().SetValue(newName); //update path element to new filename in assetmap
            }

            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**Where I'm calling the method:**

In this example I'm saying look 3 directories up from the user selected XML for the ASSETMAP.xml:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (checkBox4.Checked)
            {     
                var myList = listBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();

                foreach (var listitem in myList)
                {
                    string folder = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(listitem, "..\\..\\..\\"));
                    FindChildren(listitem, folder);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }                      
    }
```

**Condensed XML that I'm parsing to create the array of uuid's to look for:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompositionPlaylist xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/2067-3/2016" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Id>urn:uuid:f3412d2a-b7c6-4b88-8298-4b1287eb6b7f</Id>
  <Annotation>test</Annotation>
  <IssueDate>2018-03-14T18:04:50-00:00</IssueDate>
  <SegmentList>
<Segment>
  <Id>urn:uuid:2213e126-8943-44f2-b648-2ee1966bcae6</Id>
  <SequenceList>
    <cc:MainImageSequence xmlns:cc="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/2067-2/2016">
      <Id>urn:uuid:f24457fa-f9f0-4f98-823d-37b315076846</Id>
      <TrackId>urn:uuid:4fe07410-9a36-41e8-90dc-6d948b6c9965</TrackId>
      <ResourceList>
        <Resource xsi:type="TrackFileResourceType">
          <Id>urn:uuid:e6dda0de-d3b3-4132-b243-c5a32f906071</Id>
          <Annotation>VIDEO_e6dda0de-d3b3-4132-b243-c5a32f906071.mxf</Annotation>
          <EditRate>24000 1001</EditRate>
          <IntrinsicDuration>120</IntrinsicDuration>
          <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
          <SourceDuration>120</SourceDuration>
          <SourceEncoding>urn:uuid:b54c9259-db31-4c26-a2f1-1fb2d9289a91</SourceEncoding>
          <TrackFileId>urn:uuid:e6dda0de-d3b3-4132-b243-c5a32f906071</TrackFileId>
          <Hash>6dj4cRq4fjj0hFHiCkzelQaBsmI=</Hash>
        </Resource>
      </ResourceList>
    </cc:MainImageSequence>
    <cc:MainAudioSequence xmlns:cc="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/2067-2/2016">
      <Id>urn:uuid:0482c0a9-a9bf-4eef-8242-827f5fc0ed04</Id>
      <TrackId>urn:uuid:8ee689f1-d8d2-47d0-9aab-0649bc8dd107</TrackId>
      <ResourceList>
        <Resource xsi:type="TrackFileResourceType">
          <Id>urn:uuid:d669a9dc-bb65-4e6c-8ca5-8c4c7db78366</Id>
          <Annotation>AUDIO_d669a9dc-bb65-4e6c-8ca5-8c4c7db78366.mxf</Annotation>
          <EditRate>48000 1</EditRate>
          <IntrinsicDuration>240240</IntrinsicDuration>
          <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
          <SourceDuration>240240</SourceDuration>
          <SourceEncoding>urn:uuid:12c5eb01-05ec-4a52-a849-a93a75a81abe</SourceEncoding>
          <TrackFileId>urn:uuid:d669a9dc-bb65-4e6c-8ca5-8c4c7db78366</TrackFileId>
          <Hash>LqYEfjfJ4Ut868Ev7dEPAOZ2pQU=</Hash>
        </Resource>
      </ResourceList>
    </cc:MainAudioSequence>
    <cc:MainAudioSequence xmlns:cc="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/2067-2/2016">
      <Id>urn:uuid:a982cff3-45b6-4c13-9983-10a1c4c7cba6</Id>
      <TrackId>urn:uuid:650715f4-fd76-49b8-af67-86064d68e883</TrackId>
      <ResourceList>
        <Resource xsi:type="TrackFileResourceType">
          <Id>urn:uuid:56b010e4-f3e1-46f6-87e9-80b6ea099651</Id>
          <Annotation>AUDIO_56b010e4-f3e1-46f6-87e9-80b6ea099651.mxf</Annotation>
          <EditRate>48000 1</EditRate>
          <IntrinsicDuration>240240</IntrinsicDuration>
          <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
          <SourceDuration>240240</SourceDuration>
          <SourceEncoding>urn:uuid:2ddc6740-96ab-4a68-b9fb-57db49642089</SourceEncoding>
          <TrackFileId>urn:uuid:56b010e4-f3e1-46f6-87e9-80b6ea099651</TrackFileId>
          <Hash>4u6ErtEdI9pXNIMDrQ/EB/aKuw8=</Hash>
        </Resource>
      </ResourceList>
    </cc:MainAudioSequence>
    <cc:SubtitlesSequence xmlns:cc="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/2067-2/2016">
      <Id>urn:uuid:d4825bd1-a294-41f7-820c-2b7658e06415</Id>
      <TrackId>urn:uuid:31535e83-89ee-4e29-a8f4-d9a36eaff215</TrackId>
      <ResourceList>
        <Resource xsi:type="TrackFileResourceType">
          <Id>urn:uuid:fbb9e1cc-6f2e-43b3-a01c-a3b34d04252a</Id>
          <Annotation>SUB_fbb9e1cc-6f2e-43b3-a01c-a3b34d04252a.mxf</Annotation>
          <EditRate>24000 1001</EditRate>
          <IntrinsicDuration>120</IntrinsicDuration>
          <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
          <SourceDuration>120</SourceDuration>
          <SourceEncoding>urn:uuid:8562a7a6-43a4-4e30-bf6b-7b541ccfa900</SourceEncoding>
          <TrackFileId>urn:uuid:fbb9e1cc-6f2e-43b3-a01c-a3b34d04252a</TrackFileId>
          <Hash>eJVhYF6TuOo/vu7KE6qsmFqUnUk=</Hash>
        </Resource>
      </ResourceList>
    </cc:SubtitlesSequence>
  </SequenceList>
</Segment>
```

`

**Sample XML that I'm searching for (ASSETMAP.xml).** There may be more than one, hence the foreach loop.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AssetMap xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/429-9/2007/AM">
  <Id>urn:uuid:94958496-dde9-49b0-ad50-1dda6d4bba67</Id>
  <Creator>test</Creator>
  <VolumeCount>1</VolumeCount>
  <IssueDate>2018-03-14T17:59:32-00:00</IssueDate>
  <AssetList>
    <Asset>
  <Id>urn:uuid:c1eab1db-5218-46c7-a05f-0e304083f604</Id>
  <PackingList>true</PackingList>
  <ChunkList>
    <Chunk>
      <Path>PKL_c1eab1db-5218-46c7-a05f-0e304083f604.xml</Path>
      <VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
      <Length>3063</Length>
    </Chunk>
  </ChunkList>
</Asset>
<Asset>
  <Id>urn:uuid:393c1a9b-1907-4dd0-a3a9-5299b0dcdedf</Id>
  <ChunkList>
    <Chunk>
      <Path>CPL_IMF_JOT_Sample_ML5HDR10_OV.xml</Path>
      <VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
      <Length>22807</Length>
    </Chunk>
  </ChunkList>
</Asset>
<Asset>
  <Id>urn:uuid:e6dda0de-d3b3-4132-b243-c5a32f906071</Id>
  <ChunkList>
    <Chunk>
      <Path>VIDEO_e6dda0de-d3b3-4132-b243-c5a32f906071.mxf</Path>
      <VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
      <Length>14745242</Length>
    </Chunk>
  </ChunkList>
</Asset>
<Asset>
  <Id>urn:uuid:56b010e4-f3e1-46f6-87e9-80b6ea099651</Id>
  <ChunkList>
    <Chunk>
      <Path>AUDIO_56b010e4-f3e1-46f6-87e9-80b6ea099651.mxf</Path>
      <VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
      <Length>4341294</Length>
    </Chunk>
  </ChunkList>
</Asset>
<Asset>
  <Id>urn:uuid:d669a9dc-bb65-4e6c-8ca5-8c4c7db78366</Id>
  <ChunkList>
    <Chunk>
      <Path>AUDIO_d669a9dc-bb65-4e6c-8ca5-8c4c7db78366.mxf</Path>
      <VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
      <Length>1458414</Length>
    </Chunk>
  </ChunkList>
</Asset>
<Asset>
  <Id>urn:uuid:f17087ab-50ea-4537-8d1b-f53b54bd8ea8</Id>
  <ChunkList>
    <Chunk>
      <Path>SUB_f17087ab-50ea-4537-8d1b-f53b54bd8ea8.mxf</Path>
      <VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
      <Length>34509</Length>
    </Chunk>
  </ChunkList>
</Asset>
<Asset>
  <Id>urn:uuid:809da04c-8daf-4835-9ae5-889e7f93d18e</Id>
  <ChunkList>
    <Chunk>
      <Path>OPL_809da04c-8daf-4835-9ae5-889e7f93d18e.xml</Path>
      <VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
      <Length>725</Length>
    </Chunk>
  </ChunkList>
</Asset>
```

`

Comment: For #2 Create a list, before calling `continue` add the item to it. After the loop output all items in the list. #1 is not clear to me. Some tips: no need for all the extra parens around variables ie:  `(assetname)` ; `GetFiles` returns an array of strings so you don't need the `ToString()`. I don't think you even need *that* call either—it appears you expect to find an exact filename in that directory just use `var assetpath = Path.Combine(assetmapdir, assetname);` unless you're doing so to make sure it exists in which case `File.Exists` will prevent a NRE when nothing is returned/empty array

Comment: If I had a sample of the xml I could probably find a much better way of achieving the results.  Based on code try starting with following : var results =  assetElements.Select(assetC =>  new { id = assetC.Descendants(assetns + "Id").FirstOrDefault().Value, name = assetC.Descendants(assetns + "Path").FirstOrDefault().Value}).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your comments. I have provided more context and xmls above.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks for your comments. I have provided more context and xmls above.

Answer (score 1):

I like using dictionaries to group ids.  Below I used xml linq to do all the parsing.  Below is just a start but if you need additional help just let me know.  I'm not sure which IDs need to match.  The code below is not finding any matches.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] cplFILENAMES = { @"c:\temp\test.xml" };
        static string[] assetFILENAMES = { @"c:\temp\test1.xml" };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string filename in cplFILENAMES)
            {
                new CompositionPlayList(filename);
            }
            foreach (string filename in assetFILENAMES)
            {
                new AssetMap(filename);
            }

            var groups = (from cpl in CompositionPlayList.dictSequences
                          join asset in AssetMap.dictAsset on cpl.Key equals asset.Key into a
                          from asset in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new { id = cpl.Key, cpl = cpl.Value, asset = asset.Value }).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class CompositionPlayList
    {

        public string filename { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime issueDate { get; set; }
        public string segmentID { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<string, Sequence> dictSequences = new Dictionary<string, Sequence>();

        public CompositionPlayList() { }
        public CompositionPlayList(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            XElement cpl = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = cpl.GetDefaultNamespace();


            this.filename = filename;
            id = ((string)cpl.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault();

            issueDate = (DateTime)cpl.Element(ns + "IssueDate");

            XElement segment = cpl.Descendants(ns + "Segment").FirstOrDefault();
            segmentID = ((string)segment.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault();

            List<XElement> sequences = segment.Element(ns + "SequenceList").Elements().ToList();

            XNamespace ccNs = sequences.FirstOrDefault().GetNamespaceOfPrefix("cc");

            Dictionary<string, Sequence> newDictSequences = sequences.Select(x => new Sequence
            {
                sequenceType = x.Name.LocalName,
                id = ((string)x.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault(),
                trackID = ((string)x.Element(ns + "TrackId")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault()
                filename = filename;
            }).GroupBy(x => x.trackID, y => y)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Sequence> sequence in newDictSequences)
            {
                dictSequences.Add(sequence.Key, sequence.Value);
            }
        }

    }
    public class Sequence
    {
        public string sequenceType { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string trackID { get; set; }
        public string filename { get; set; }
    }
    public class AssetMap
    {
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime issueDate { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<string, Asset> dictAsset = new Dictionary<string, Asset>();

        public AssetMap() { }
        public AssetMap(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            XElement assetMap = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = assetMap.GetDefaultNamespace();

            this.filename = filename;
            id = ((string)assetMap.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault();

            issueDate = (DateTime)assetMap.Element(ns + "IssueDate");

            List<XElement> assets = assetMap.Element(ns + "AssetList").Elements().ToList();

            Dictionary<string, Asset> newDictAsset = assets.Select(x => new Asset
            {
                id = ((string)x.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault()
            }).GroupBy(x => x.id, y => y)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Asset> sequence in newDictAsset)
            {
                dictAsset.Add(sequence.Key, sequence.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Asset
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

    }

}
```

---

I originally used a dictionary to make lookup quicker.  Now that I'm using a left outer join the dictionary isn't needed so below is a more efficient version of the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] cplFILENAMES = { @"c:\temp\test.xml" };
        static string[] assetFILENAMES = { @"c:\temp\test1.xml" };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string filename in cplFILENAMES)
            {
                new CompositionPlayList(filename);
            }
            foreach (string filename in assetFILENAMES)
            {
                new AssetMap(filename);
            }

            var groups = (from cpl in CompositionPlayList.sequences
                          join asset in AssetMap.assets on cpl.trackID equals asset.id into a
                          from asset in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new { id = cpl.id, cpl = cpl.trackID, asset = asset}).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class CompositionPlayList
    {

        public string filename { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime issueDate { get; set; }
        public string segmentID { get; set; }

        public static List<Sequence> sequences = new List<Sequence>();

        public CompositionPlayList() { }
        public CompositionPlayList(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            XElement cpl = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = cpl.GetDefaultNamespace();


            this.filename = filename;
            id = ((string)cpl.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault();

            issueDate = (DateTime)cpl.Element(ns + "IssueDate");

            XElement segment = cpl.Descendants(ns + "Segment").FirstOrDefault();
            segmentID = ((string)segment.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault();

            List<XElement> sequences = segment.Element(ns + "SequenceList").Elements().ToList();

            XNamespace ccNs = sequences.FirstOrDefault().GetNamespaceOfPrefix("cc");

            List<Sequence> newSequences = sequences.Select(x => new Sequence {
                sequenceType = x.Name.LocalName,
                id = ((string)x.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault(),
                trackID = ((string)x.Element(ns + "TrackId")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault(),
                filename = filename
            }).ToList();

            CompositionPlayList.sequences.AddRange(newSequences);
        }

    }
    public class Sequence
    {
        public string sequenceType { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string trackID { get; set; }
        public string filename { get; set; }
    }
    public class AssetMap
    {
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime issueDate { get; set; }

        public static List<AssetMap> assets = new List<AssetMap>();

        public AssetMap() { }
        public AssetMap(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            XElement assetMap = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = assetMap.GetDefaultNamespace();

            this.filename = filename;
            id = ((string)assetMap.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault();

            issueDate = (DateTime)assetMap.Element(ns + "IssueDate");

            List<XElement> assets = assetMap.Element(ns + "AssetList").Elements().ToList();

            List<AssetMap> newAssets = assets.Select(x => new AssetMap() { id = ((string)x.Element(ns + "Id")).Split(new char[] { ':' }).LastOrDefault(), filename = filename, issueDate = issueDate }).ToList();

            AssetMap.assets.AddRange(newAssets);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it, but looks like it might work. To clarify, the only XML element values I need to compare between the CPL and ASSETMAP, are the uuid values from: CPL = `TrackFileId` and ASSETMAP = `Asset` --> `Id`. Basically, if a CPL `TrackFileId` is found in an`ASSETMAP` `Id` element, I need to construct the corresponding filepath (the file will always live is same dir as ASSETMAP), and make a hard link to it in a different user specified dir. I assume that would be the `var = groups` list you are creating, right? Does that help clarify?

Comment: Also, if any of the CPL uuids / `TrackFileIds` are not found in any ASSETMAP files, I need to show the user those values at the end of the execution.

Comment: I made some minor changes.  Made CPL use track id instead of id.  Then I change the join to a left outer join so when there are not matches the CPL shows up but asset is null.  So you can check if the asset is null to determine if a match is found.

Comment: I also added filename to sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help with this. Since this is very different than my current method, it's taking me some time to see if i can get it to work. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I added a 2nd version of the code without the dictionary which will make it easier for you to get working and is easier to understand.  The newer code uses less memory because I'm not saving the assets XElements (just the ids).  Also changed in the join the asset track id instead of the id.